# Can you edit an outlook calendar invite you didn't create

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a user that wants to add information to the subject line of a calendar invite she didn't not create.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Nope unless you are setup as an admin that owns that person's entire calendar. Contact the meeting creator to make the change.

Comment: Do you want to update the invite so that all attendees see the changes you made? Or do you just want to change the invite in your Outlook view? For the former, you have to contact the organizer or you need enough permission on the calendar to edit the invite. For the later, you can just open the invite message, edit and save changes. Remember that your changes may be lost when the organizer sends an update to the meeting invite.

Answer (score 6):

That depends on the situation. The question was not specific enough to answer it easily, but luckily there aren't many flavors, so answering all conditions is not too much in this case.

A meeting can be changed by the following people:

- The person who hosts the meeting. This can be more than one person, but if no settings were altered, it will be the person who sent out the invite (organizer).
- Someone who manages the mailbox of someone else where the invite was sent from. In that case, both the person who sent the invite and the person who manages their account will be able to alter the meeting. Think of a manager and their secretary.

These persons can alter the meeting and send updates to everyone in the meeting.

The exception here is changing the date. When anyone receives the invite, they may propose a new date, but its up to the host to accept that proposal or not.

Next to this, it is actually possible for everyone to edit the appointment that appears in their own calendar, such as editing a title, deleting it etc. It will only be edited in their calendar though, and can be overwritten if the host sends out an update, and you accept that update.

Comment: It seems like I'm now no longer able to edit a meeting invite that someone else sent in Outlook 2016 for the Mac.  I like to change my meetings after the fact to show whether they ended early or late, but this functionality seems to have been disabled recently.

Comment: @RyanGross please create a new question if you have a new problem. Commenting on answers is meant to point out faults or otherwise discuss answers without it turning into a long discussion. In your case, you have a new problem that should have its own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to request permissions to the meeting host to edit the meeting details. You can see how to do this here (is not easy by the way): https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/7321-outlook-cancel-meeting-as-not-organizer.html#app

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1212786)

Comment: @Toto, you can also amplify my reply. If you really have the intention to provide full answers, it's also in your hand to add text and comments to provide essential parts. The link I posted is public. Here are the steps: 1. Enable Outlook, click Calendar icon to switch to the calendar view. 2. Right-click on the calendar to share, click Share>Share Calendar. 3. In the Sharing invitation dialog, add the email you want to share the calendar to the To field, then tick Recipient can add, edit, and delete items in this calendar checkbox, and click Send. A dialog pops to confirm changes.