# Can one categorize/colour incoming outlook invitations? (Outlook web app office365)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar

I have a series of recurring meetings from an incoming invitation. I would like to colour them specific to that series so I can see them clearly.

Noting this answer: [Can you edit an outlook calendar invite you didn't create](https://superuser.com/questions/1378537/can-you-edit-an-outlook-calendar-invite-you-didnt-create) - I don't want to edit the content of the invitation, just the colour it appears in my calendar on the web app.

Further, I do not want to colour all meetings from the one sender the same, as there are a range of different recurring and non-recurring meetings for different purposes from that sender that I would like to see differently.

As far as I can tell, the only way to do this would be to duplicate them all with my own entries, and then colour those. I don't want to do this in case they change.

I do not have access to the mailbox of the sender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just right click the meetings and select Categorize them manually. Or you can set a rule for this via Settings > View all Outlook settings > Mail > Rules.
[image][image]

Comment: This is wack behaviour from microsoft. So obvious, yet so stupid - one can categorize them directly from right click, but not if one expands the invitation and looks at the details menus at the top, where one can categorize one's own entries. Ridiculous. Great answer thanks