# How can I edit an Outlook 365 invite in my calendar if I am not the organizer?

Tags: calendar, editing

There is no Edit option in the events I have in my Outlook 365 calendar if I didn't create the event. I would like to modify the subject line of the meeting, the real estimated duration, etc. Thanks!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1378537/can-you-edit-an-outlook-calendar-invite-you-didnt-create

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you edit an outlook calendar invite you didn't create](https://superuser.com/questions/1378537/can-you-edit-an-outlook-calendar-invite-you-didnt-create)